# is it possible to programatically Change default install location of apps in Android firmware, not in app manifest

Tags: android, android-firmware

i am building a custom firmware for my android box and would like to know if it is possible to force all apps to install on SD card?
i know the ADB way. but i want to do the change in android SDK before compiling because i will be flashing the ROM to many boxes.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i guess my best option is to edit the parameter file of the ROM and make the internal system partition big enough for lots of apps

Answer (score 0):

brother Fahim,
this is how you increase your userdata partition size:
extract your rom image and get the parameter file and open it in text editer.

Here is an example of a parameter file:
0x00002000@0x00002000(misc),0x00006000@0x00004000(kernel),0x00008000@0x0000A000(boot),0x00020000@0x00012000(recovery),0x00020000@0x00032000(backup),0x00040000@0x00052000(cache),0x00200000@0x00092000(userdata),0x00002000@0x00292000(kpanic),0x00180000@0x00294000(system),-@0x00414000(user)

these numbers are in hexadecimal and are blocks of 512 bytes. 512 bytes means 200 in hex.
look at the userdata part: 0x00200000@0x00092000(userdata)
The second number 0x00092000 is the offset into the NAND chip from 0 location. dont touch this

The first number 0x00200000 is the size of the partition. so it is 200000 blocks of 200 thats 200kx200=40000000 bytes in hex. 
use pc calculator and change view to programmer.put 200000 in hex multiply by 200 then convert to decimal you get 1073,741,824 bytes which is 1Gb of userdata.

to make that 2Gb for e.g just double the 200000. so it becomes 0x00400000@0x00092000(userdata). and so on..

do not mess anything else otherwise your ROM wont work